# SQL replace any number

Tags: mysql

I am in MySql. I have the table named blog and the column photo. I want to make some changes for instance. All the values in that column have that schema: 
nunber/text.svg
For instance: 1/marketing.svg

I want to delete the number/
In the example, I want to have: text.svg. 
But I want it work with any number, one, two or three digits.

This is what I tried

```
UPDATE blog 
SET photo = REPLACE(photo, '%/', '')
```

Comment: just find the position of '/' in the string and keep everything to the right of it. using substring functions

Comment: MySQL has INSTR(str,substr) Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string format is consistent, i.e. a number followed by a `/` and then the text, you can use a combination of `substring` and `locate` to update the column.

```
UPDATE blog 
SET photo = SUBSTRING(photo, LOCATE('/',photo)+1)
WHERE LOCATE('/',photo) > 0
```